# IBM Watson Assistant I am trying to create a Master-Child Workspaces because my intent limits has reached?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am building a career information chatbot.

1. In the master workspace student is identified either High-School or College
2. Two children workspaces (high school, college) to handle students based on their identification.

Problem is that my Master/Router workspace is not transferring the user to the child workspace.

Context variable with the workspace skill IDs are set but still not working.

Comment: Add more details on what you are doing, any code. "still not working" is not a helpful description

Comment: In the managed context, it shows the workspace_id but doesn't transfer the control. Secondly, all the work is done in Watson so no code.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do. Are you on the assistant or skill? What type of skill? What are you adding and where?

Comment: One Assistant with 3 dialog skills. 1 dialog skill is the master while the other two are child skills.

Comment: Currently there is no built in method to transfer conversations between skills. So if you are directing questions to workspace A, and then expect it to switch to workspace B that will not happen. The only way to perform this action is to create your own user interface which alters the API call parameters to the Watson backend. So you perform an API call to workspace A, then alter the API call and open a second workspace.  You cannot test via one of the built-in integration methods, as these only work to one workspace at a time.

Comment: You may wish to view the following: 
https://medium.com/ibm-data-ai/training-considerations-for-multiple-skills-orchestration-5d33ef7e7936
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55997393/how-to-switch-between-skills-on-watson-assistant
https://github.com/IBM/watson-assistant-multi-bot-agent